# AutoSize text in a fixed-sized label to avoid text jumping to second line

Tags: c#, string, winforms, label, autosize

I have a label with a fixed size, approximately 100 pixel width and 20 pixel height.

When I place a long string into the label, the text wraps to the second line but I cannot see the second line because the size of the label is fixed.

Instead of wrapping to the second line, I want the fontsize to shrink so that the string is displayed on a single line in the label. Does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

**EDIT:**

The below code is working for me (most of the time). I didn't want to do anything recursive. There are times when the text still spills over to another line. I assume because I can't truly use the entire width of the label. How do I compensate for that?

```
private void Label_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = sender as Label;

    if (label != null && label.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        SizeF size = new SizeF();
        using (Graphics g = label.CreateGraphics())
        {
            size = g.MeasureString(label.Text, label.Font);
        }

        Single x = (label.Width) / size.Width;
        Single y = (label.Height) / size.Height;
        Single scaler = x > y ? y : x;

        using (Font font = label.Font)
        {
            label.Font = new Font(font.Name, font.SizeInPoints * scaler);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the font size like that isn't really going to work. For most fonts, Windows can't just create characters of any arbitrary size; instead it gives you a quantized font size as close to what you requested as possible. So sometimes you'll get a font larger than what you want and the text will wrap. Not sure why you don't want to do anything recursive here, as it will definitely work. Performance wouldn't be any problem at all.

Comment: good answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25448687

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy to do. Use [Graphics.MeasureString(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) to determine the width required for your string, then progressively make the font smaller and smaller until the width required for the string is equal to or less than the width of your label.

Comment: Label uses TextRenderer by default, using Graphics.MeasureString() is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `System.Windows.Forms.Label.TextChanged`-event and check the length of the string.

```
private void Label_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    System.Windows.Forms.Label label = sender as label;
    if(label != null){
       //check text-length and if necessary resize it
    } 
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) for `TextChanged`-event.

There is the `FontHeight`-property, which might do your trick. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fontheight.aspx) for a reference.

And if everything fails, derive from `System.Windows.Forms.Label` and create your own custom label.