# Fit Label size to drawn text

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm using a Label to display progress to the user. This occurs many times and the partly user-defined text changes every time.

**Problem:** I should know if the drawn text is bigger than the Label's size.

I tried this approach:

```
using (Graphics g = lbl.CreateGraphics()) {
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString(lbl.Text, lbl.Font);
    // Change size of label if too small
}
```

but it is too slow and uses a lot resources when calling at every update.

So is there a way to find out when the drawn text is bigger than the Label?

**EDIT:**
As stated by Hans Passant, `AutoSize` will do it.
Sorry, I didn't say that other controls below the Label has to move then.

Comment: You are trying to resize the label?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527721/resize-text-size-of-a-label-when-the-text-got-longer-than-the-label-size

Comment: @butterbox: Thanks, but your linked question is about resizing the font. I want to resize the label.

Comment: It already knows how to do that, leave its AutoSize property set to True.  If that is "slow" then you are doing it wrong, this only needs to be fast enough for human eyes.  Which are **way** slower than MeasureString().  Simply throttle your update rate.

Comment: Then you should layout the form to have everything in a `TableLayoutPanel` or something similar.  That will take care of readjusting position as the relative sizes change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no other way to do it.
So I have to use the above solution:

```
using (Graphics g = lbl.CreateGraphics()) {
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString(lbl.Text, lbl.Font);
    // Change size of label if too small
}
```