# Resize asp:Label at runtime

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to allow the client to re-size the Label's Text size at runtime.

jQuery Resizable isn't working, it only worked on textboxes / dropdownlists and so on, but for the Label it did not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize text size of a label when the text got longer than the label size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527721/resize-text-size-of-a-label-when-the-text-got-longer-than-the-label-size)

Comment: @X - Developer your example is for win forms.

Comment: @smirnov I know it works for winforms, so webforms doesn't allow such behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the resize() event of resizable()

Example

```
<style>
.lbl {display:block}
</style>

...
<asp:Label ID="Label1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" 
    Text="Label" CssClass="lbl"></asp:Label>

...
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#label" ).resizable({
           resize: function( event, ui ) {
               var height = ui.element.height(); 
               ui.element.css({'font-size':height+'%'});
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/cotiribo/2/edit?html,output

Comment: This will only re-size the block, won't affect the text's size of the label, i wanna be able to re-size the label's text size.

Comment: See updated code and a new demo

Comment: is there any way to make it without the display block ? same principal but only on label

Comment: No, the resizable() will not work for a span without display block. You can use div instead of span if you want (but in this case you would need to do something like <div runat="server" id="Label1"> or similar)