# How to alter text size in a label dynamically?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I'm working for  making a user interface which supports multiple languages, hence the text lengths in the labels of the forms may vary. I need help with  re-sizing text size  whenever required so that the text fits within the label.

Comment: I think your answer should be there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-a-label-in-windows-forms

Comment: I think I might have found my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527721/resize-text-size-of-a-label-when-the-text-got-longer-than-the-label-size