# Fit label size to the available space?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using labels in a Windows Form application. These labels are dynamic so the text they show are constantly changing. How can I resize each label accordingly to the character number it shows and the available space in a splitcontainer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527721/resize-text-size-of-a-label-when-the-text-got-longer-than-the-label-size

Comment: It doesn't properly work @Roxy'Pro. Any other suggestion?